# Django: html links to the wrong directory for the css

Tags: html, css, django

Here is my main page, localhost:8000/helloworld/greeter at helloworld\templates\hello:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Hello!</title>
        {% load static%}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{% static 'hello/site.css' %}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="message">Hello there, {{ name }}!</span> It's {{ date | date:'l, d F, Y' }} at {{ date | time:'H:i:s' }}.
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS file at helloworld\static\hello (so it should look for localhost:8000\helloworld\static\hello\site.css):

```
.message{
    font-weight
    color: blue;
}
```

and here is the file structure: [image]

The expected behaviour would be that the phrase "Hello there, [name]" is bolded and in blue, but here is what the code actually yields: (this is the problem)
[image: Incorrect]
And looking within the console gives this error:
`GET http://localhost:8000/static/hello/site.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Notice how it seems to think that "static" is at the root directory, when it is in localhost\helloworld.

I would like to find a solution to this problem and change it so that it links to the correct directory

I tried to change the  block, specifically:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{% static 'hello/site.css' %}" />
```

to：

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "{% 'helloworld/static/hello/site.css' %}" />
```

I expect that it will apply the site.css but it didn't and threw a TemplateSyntaxError.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed like so:

In the file settings.py, I changed the line to become `STATIC_URL = '/helloworld/static/'`

Comment: This is (probably) not the way to do it, if you're going to have multiple applets inside of your project.

Comment: The tutorial I'm following said nothing about this condition so I fixed it in the most quick and dirty way possible; if there's a different way please do tell me

Comment: Sure. There are several SO posts on this subject; off the top of my head, I think the common problems are: 1) You applet isn't in "installed apps" list in settings.py, 2) `{ load static}` isn't in your HTML, which is not the case, 3) in your applet folder, you should have a folder called `static`, which has a subfolder with the same name as your applet, which contains all your static files for that applet, which could be the problem in your case, 4) you're are putting the static directory in the same directory as settings.py, which doesn't appear to be the case, but could be.

Comment: Before making these changes, if you choose to make them, you should make a backup of your project - I'd hate for my advice to brake your working solution.